# Bash seems to be executing command 2nd time when variable of captured output is used

Tags: php, bash

```
OUTPUT=$(php -f somecommand arg1 arg2 arg3 2>&1)
echo "$OUTPUT" >> error.log
```

The script runs by cron. In the emailed output I received it looks like the `php -f ...` command was run twice.

Is it run once when the variable is set, and again when the variable is echoed? I don't remember this behavior happening before.

If that is what is happening... then how do I get the program output into the variable without re-executing the program?

Comment: It's not run twice as you describe, it'd be run just once and the output stored in OUTPUT.  You are appending it to `error.log` though, is it perhaps just that you saw it run the first time, then added the next output and saw two instances in the log since you aren't clearing it between runs?

Comment: @EricRenouf yes it's possible, I suppose. It is just strange that in my emailed output after the second output I see a PHP error. It makes me think it ran twice. I will see if I can learn more.